# What could make my node app stop working on Heroku?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I deployed my node app to heroku and it worked fine. Now I do not know what I tampered with which makes it stop working but rather throwing some undecipherable errors.

I'll appreciate your help as I have spent up to 5 hours on this.
here is the error:

````
2020-11-20T20:02:29.805108+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
2020-11-20T20:02:29.805109+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
2020-11-20T20:02:29.805109+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
2020-11-20T20:02:29.805109+00:00 app[web.1]:     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
2020-11-20T20:02:29.805192+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:23) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
2020-11-20T20:02:29.805266+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:23) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
2020-11-20T20:02:29.903831+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-11-20T20:02:30.968848+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=mqjreaders.herokuapp.com request_id=21ca5862-c25d-434f-a8ba-57515954eed1 fwd="197.210.65.117" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=28ms status=302 bytes=375 protocol=https
2020-11-20T20:03:01.467843+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/posts" host=mqjreaders.herokuapp.com request_id=b50c1b83-a2c3-4136-a091-67a0be9eb0a5 fwd="197.210.65.117" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=30004ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https```

/ ===========
// AUTH ROUTES
// ============

// show signup/register form

```router.get("/register", function(req, res){
  res.render("register");
});```
````

Comment: Did you add a default error handler for all routes?

Comment: yeah, I did for most but I think a few were left out. Here is my main route:      var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
var passport = require("passport");
var User     = require("../models/user");


router.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.redirect("/posts");
});


// ===========
// AUTH ROUTES
// ============

// show signup/register form

router.get("/register", function(req, res){
  res.render("register");
});

Comment: please add it to your post

Comment: Please don't add code pieces to comment. It's very hard to read them there

Comment: Just did that. Thanks for your timeAnatoly.

Comment: Does that mean all errors must be handled?

Comment: Yes, such a handler helps to catch unexpected errors. All expected ones should be handled inside route handlers.

Comment: `app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    logger.error(err)

    res.status(500).send(`<pre>${err.stack}</pre>`)
  })
`

Comment: Alright, thanks! I'll try fixing that.